# How to set an hardware breakpoint in aarch64?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, arm64

I am interested in generating a breakpoint exception in arm64 (aarch64), using [LiteOS](https://gitee.com/liteos) as working OS. To not be unclear, a Breakpoint exception is generated whenever the processor element tries to execute an instruction from a particular address (this shouldn't be confused with "breakpoint instruction exceptions", i.e. instruction `bkpt` or `int`, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345371/how-do-i-set-a-software-breakpoint-on-an-arm-processor)).

The section BREAKPOINT EXCEPTION of [AARCH64 manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102120/0100/Debug-exceptions) treats what I want to achieve (and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755446/setting-a-hardware-breakpoint-in-arm64) as well, but it didn't solve my problem).

Before explaining my problem, let me say that I verified that my CPU supports hardware breakpoints: bits [15:12] of register `ID_AA64DFR0_EL1` (manual [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-06/AArch64-Registers/ID-AA64DFR0-EL1--AArch64-Debug-Feature-Register-0)) are `0b1010` = 5-1 = `4` breakpoint supported.

In my userspace, I have a simple function:

```
void justAFunction()
{
    printf("justAFunction has been called, did you block?\n");
}
```

Before calling this function, the userland process "set a breakpoint":

```
[...]
setBreakpoint((void *)justAFunction); /* this is a system call to the kernel */
[...]
justAFunction();
[...]
```

`setBreakpoint` is a system call, and I implemented the kernel code as follow (like kvm code, the only reference I found in this respect, [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17-rc5/source/tools/testing/selftests/kvm/aarch64/debug-exceptions.c#L67)):

```
void setBreakpoint(void *addr)
{   
    AARCH64_SYSREG_WRITE(DBGBVR0_EL1, addr);
    AARCH64_SYSREG_WRITE(DBGBCR0_EL1, (AARCH64_SYSREG_READ(DBGBCR0_EL1) | DBGBCR_E | DBGBCR_LEN8 | DBGBCR_EXEC | DBGBCR_EL1));
    isb();

    asm volatile("msr daifclr, #8");

    AARCH64_SYSREG_WRITE(mdscr_el1, (AARCH64_SYSREG_READ(mdscr_el1) | MDSCR_KDE | MDSCR_MDE));
    isb();
}
```

Description for `DBGBCR0_EL1` and `DBGBVR0_EL1`: [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102120/0100/Debug-exceptions).

Specifically:

```
#define DBGBCR_LEN8 (0xff << 5)
#define DBGBCR_EXEC (0x0 << 3)
#define DBGBCR_EL1  (0x1 << 1)
#define DBGBCR_E    (0x1 << 0)
#define MDSCR_KDE   (1 << 13)
#define MDSCR_MDE   (1 << 15)
```

After trying to write `addr` (namely `justAFunction` virtual address) to `DBGBVR0_EL1`, I tried to re-read the same register, and the content was correct.

What I expected is to raise a debug exception (which are enabled in my kernel because I am able to raise a breakpoint instruction like `bkpt` or to single-step my application) once the userland process tried to execute `justAFunction`.

Unfortunately, nothing happens. `justAFunction` is executed and the exception vector is not triggered (I have verified with gdb).

My feeling is that I missed something, but I can't find what.

Answer (score 1):

You want your breakpoint to hit at EL0, but you configure it for EL1. Drop the `DBGBCR_EL1` flag.

Also, you probably don't want to read the current contents of `DBGBCR0_EL1`, but rather overwrite them completely.

Replace this:

```c
AARCH64_SYSREG_WRITE(DBGBCR0_EL1, (AARCH64_SYSREG_READ(DBGBCR0_EL1) | DBGBCR_E | DBGBCR_LEN8 | DBGBCR_EXEC | DBGBCR_EL1));
```

with this:

```c
AARCH64_SYSREG_WRITE(DBGBCR0_EL1, (DBGBCR_E | DBGBCR_LEN8 | DBGBCR_EXEC));
```

Comment: Hello @Siguza, thanks for your answer. What you say it's always pertinent. 
I still have doubts, sorry. I don't think registers `DBGBCR_EL0` and `DBGBVR_EL0` exist. How can I target EL0? Thanks

Comment: That's not what I meant. I clarified my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, I still can't get the exception ...